# How to make Large TextView flow by pages instead of vertical scrollview and I have to make swipe it by pages till the end of the file?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am reading the text file and viewing it in the TextView. After the line number 'thirty one' (31) remaining lines are beyond the screen size.

- consider the String viewText has 50 lines of text.

Instead of viewing it by scrolling the page through scroll bar, i need to flow the remaining contents to next page by creating through code. I should keep on adding pages till it reads the complete file. And while reading swiping pages left for previous and right for next page till it reach end of the file.

I hereby add screenshot of code and screenshot of the emulator.
As I was new to Android. I don't know how to achieve it.

Can anyone please suggest me how to achieve it. Thanks a lot it advance.

```
public class ChapterFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String yy = " ";
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int i = getArguments().getInt(yy);

        if(i == 0) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_content_frame, container, false);
            String home = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapters_array)[i];
            getActivity().setTitle(home);
            return rootView;
        } else if(i > 0) {
            String Chapter = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapters_array)[i];
            int chapid = getResources().getIdentifier(Chapter.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                    "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());

            String viewText = readTextFile(this, chapid);


            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_frame, container, false);
            Log.i("show", viewText);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.texting)).setText(viewText);

            getActivity().setTitle(Chapter);
            return rootView;
        }
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    }
```